# Antenna signal through category 5 cable

Tags: ethernet, antenna

Can an antenna signal (from an antenna cable) be transfered along with an ethernet signal through a category 5 cable? Will I lose too much signal quality?

Antenna specification:

```
Digital indoor antenna DVB-T
For terrestrial, digital signals (UHF/VHF/FM and DAB-receiving).
Frequency range: 
    VHF: 174-230 MHz
    UHF: 470-862 MHz
Amplification:
    VHF/UHF: 28 dB
Powered by included AC adapter 230V or directly via DVB-T 5V/40 mA (set top box/digital TV).
RF cable:
    IEC to F connector, 1,5 m
Size:
    Width:  115 mm
    Depth:   35 mm
    Height: 180 mm
```

The antenna manufacturer is [Biltema](http://biltema.no/). I think the antenna model is being discontinued by the manufacturer. Biltema has released a newer model, almost (at least visually) identical to the one I have, but for some reason you can't find it in the online catalog.

Comment: According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) CAT5 has a characteristic impedance of 100ohm. While I believe your UHF/VHF etc will required a 50 Ohm impedance. 
Better to find a cable that's designed for it if you need an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of antenna? What length?

You're going to need to provide a lot more information, but the short answer is *probably* no. Anything above a few Mhz, that is not specially conditioned, cannot be fed over a CAT-5 cable.

Comment: As a side note, there's also the question of interference from the signal.